# Capture all mouse events in user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent

I'm trying to capture all mouse events in a user control (even the ones that occur in child controls). For that I use the "override WndProc"-approach:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m.Msg.ToString());
  base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I'm especially interested in mouse events, but that does not seem to work. I do get mouse button up/down events, but I *don't* get mouse move and mouse wheel events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Best you could do is implement [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) in your control.

```
 public class CustomMessageFilter:UserControl,IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        //Process your message here
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
}
```

you can write your message filtering logic in ***PreFilterMessage*** Method.
Then just install it to the list of Message Filter in Main method.

```
 Application.AddMessageFilter(new CustomMessageFilter());
```

This is a Application level hook, that means you can control all the Win32 message within application.

Comment: Actually I tried that (code almost identical to what you suggested) but the method is never called.

Comment: How did you register it your user control (MessageFilter) ??

Comment: Like this:  Application.AddMessageFilter(this);  (in the UCs constructor)

Comment: No, you need to install before Message loop start, that said, before Application.Run();

Comment: Mh, and if that ain't possible? The user control will be instantiated by a native C++ application somewhere during runtime...

Comment: You can Define class without deriving from UserControl. And install it before Application.Run(..) executes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to capture all mouse events in a control is to call that control's [Control.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) method.

Typically this is a temporary state like doing drag n drop, user-drawing, and so forth.